# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined ,ng-cordova.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Am getting the cordova network error,but i installed the cordova plugin for getting network status,it throws an error on developer console.I don't find any solution for solving this error.

[image]

Also,am attaching the piece of code from my project.

[This is my project code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az2MN.png)

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () 
{
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
        //setTimeout(function() {
        //    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        //},2000);
        //    ----------------network information--starts------------
       var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();
        **var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();**
        localStorage.network_type = type;
        localStorage.isOnline = isOnline;
        localStorage.network_state;
        if (localStorage.isOnline) {
            localStorage.network_state = "online";
        } else {
            localStorage.network_state = "offline";
        }
```

Comment: Post your code in the question

Comment: am getting it in the line
var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork();

Comment: Are you including `$cordovaNetwork` as a dependency?

Comment: Yeah,I've included it .. Still getting problem.. @Dexter

Comment: Could you try wrapping the network functions in a timeout of something like 15 to 20 seconds to see if it starts working? The problem seems to be either that the plugin is not loaded at this point or that it cannot access the plugin for some reason. At least we may be able to pinpoint which of the two issues may be causing the problem.

Comment: It couldn't access the plugin,it throws the error after a timeout function,Actually it cannot able to read the **$cordovaNetwork** , I've tried reinstalling the cordova plugin with the dependencies.still the same ! @Dexter

Comment: Do u recommend any particular version of cordova network plugin ? @Dexter

Comment: I would recommend the latest of course, which is 1.2.1 at the time of writing this. Are you sure that the plugin is installed?